# My Google Apps script regex requires a match for either one expression or another.

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

The text being matched will either be an 'Issue' or 'Request' with accompanying text. e.g.

Issue:   Inspection on all Boilers

Request: Repair Feed water pump Boiler 5

If I test my expression using a javascript on line regex test utility it works as expected, however my apps script fails as only the first expression is tested and the alternative capturing group is always ignored.

```js
tmp = content.match(/Request\s{0,3}:\s{0,3}([A-Za-z0-9.,'&\s]+)(\r?\n)|Issue\s{0,3}:\s{0,3}([A-Za-z0-9.,'&\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
```

Comment: Try just `.match(/\b(?:Issue|Request)\s*:\s*(.+)/)[1]`

Comment: Yes! Thank you Wiktor, simplest is always best.

Comment: I’m not sure why that greedy expression doesn’t just capture all the text in my document after the Issue or Request but work it does.

Comment: It is due to the fact that `.` matches any char **other than line break chars**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var s = "Issue: Inspection on all Boilers\n\nRequest: Repair Feed water pump Boiler 5";
var match = s.match(/\b(?:Issue|Request)\s*:\s*(.+)/); // Get a match
if (match) {                                           // Check if there is a match first
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

The pattern matches

- `\b` -  a word boundarty
- `(?:Issue|Request)` - either `Issue` or `Request` as whole words
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars.

We first get a match using `String#match` method, then check if there is a match with `if (match)` (or, an error will pop up upon trying to access `match[1]` if there was no match) and then access the contents of the first and only capturing group using `match[1]`.

Comment: Ok Wiktor thank you for the clarity of your explanation, you have prompted me to study the regex syntax more thoroughly.